# golang - prevent app from Exiting

Tags: go, exit

In Go, with a `panic()` you can use `defer` and `recover()` to [prevent an app from exiting](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover) and continue executing code.

However, I'm trying to prevent my app from exiting when getting a `dial tcp 192.168.1.1:830: getsockopt: connection refused`. The application Exits with a status code of 1. It's technically not an error so I can't catch the error. The external package I'm using to make the tcp dial causes the app to Exit when this condition occurs. (In this case, it's because the port is blocked.)

So how can I recover the Exit from another package and continue on with my application? Take the below as an example:

```
func makeRequest(target string) {
    // Exits with status code 1, if connection refused 
    res, err := request.NewSession(target)
}
```

Comment: Is it panicking or exiting ? If the other package calls `os.Exit`, then there isn't much you can do (except maybe don't use this package :/). What package is causing the issue ?

Comment: If a library package calls `os.Exit`, *don't use that package*. That's inexcusably bad practice for a library package.

Comment: It's definitely an exit and not panic, I get `exit status 1` in stdout. The package is `https://github.com/Juniper/go-netconf` but it's using `golang.org/x/crypto/ssh` to make the calls.

Comment: I don't see any calls to Exit or Fatal in those packages. go-netconf wraps the standard logger in its own logger, which includes wrapping Fatal, but nothing calls the wrapper's Fatal, so I don't see where that lib is exiting from.

Comment: I'll have to track it down, I don't have any os.Exit() func in my own code, so it must be in those somewhere. Regardless, is there absolutely no way to recover from an Exit called in an external package?

Comment: I can [see](https://github.com/Juniper/go-netconf/blob/26f91e3c1bf4420ca4097bef42e33e2b7d729ec8/netconf/transport_ssh.go#L65) that ssh.Dial error code is passed as return value so it's not problem with this library. Can you post parts of your code that handles errors from ssh.Dial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you can't recover from a call to os.Exit(). The documentation says that it exits immediately, and not even differed functions are called. I recommend to not use a package if it has an exit in it, as that is a pretty bad design.